# How to show interstitial ads every 3 clicks in flutter dart

Tags: flutter

Im Using Ironsource Ads and the interstitial show everytime i click on a button , that's not good for my users , i want the ad to show every 3 clicks .

Comment: Please update your question and add your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set this by custom way,like
Define a local variable for count.

```
Var clickCount=0;
```

Then,

```
RaisedButton(
 shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
 onPressed: () {
setState(() { 
clickCount=clickCount+1;
If(clickCount>2){
//call your code here.


//after your action performe.
//again you will set count zero.
//clickCount=0;
}
 });
},
 child: Text("Button"),
 )
```